# Difficulty regarding grasping concept of fft butterfly?

Tags: fft

The  term "butterfly " is often used in association with fft texts
But what exactly is a butterfly
?a matrix/group of i/o's is known as butterfly? Such as 2 input 2 output butterflies in stage 1 of attached photo

How we can differentiate between butterflies of stage 1 and stage 2?other than number of i/o's?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A FFT "butterfly" is the name for an algorithmic structure inside the FFT. It

- has two complex inputs
- two complex outputs
- one complex multiply
- sum and difference of two complex numbers

There are two basic types. The decimation-in-time butterfly does the multiply first
$$y_0 = x_0 + x_1 \cdot W$$
$$ y_1 = x_0 - x_1 \cdot W $$

Decimation-in-Frequency computes the sum/difference operation first
$$ y_0 = (x_0 + x_1) $$
$$ y_1 = (x_0 - x_1) \cdot W $$

It's useful to write this in matrix notation. Decimation-in-time:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
y_0 \\ y_1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & W \\ 1 & -W 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0 \\ x_1
\end{pmatrix} $$

and decimation-in-frequency:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
y_0 \\ y_1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ W & -W 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0 \\ x_1
\end{pmatrix} $$

So the matrices are transposed of each other.

Update:

The twiddle factor $W$ is a function of which stage you are in and which butterfly inside the stage. For decimation-in-time, $W$ simply alternates between $+1$ and $-1$, i.e. $W = [+1,-1,+1,-1 ...]$ so there is no need for an actual multiplication. Similarly for the second stage we have $W=[1, -j, -1, j, 1, -j, ...]$ which also doesn't require multiplication. This property can be used to further optimize the implementation and so in many Implementation these stages are hand-coded

Comment: Very nice explanation

Comment: But it will be much better if you elaborate on differences between butterflies of stage 1 and stage 2

Comment: Your bullet number 4, sum and difference or two complex numbers

Comment: Isn't there any J term in W matrix for stage 1?

Comment: You have mentioned about W values of 2nd stage ,nice, but please explain number of io's . As apparently io's are double

Comment: each butterfly has two inputs and two outputs.